# Apex code failing validation on inbound change set

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-communities

I have three classes that I am trying to push from the sandbox to production.

Class 1 the main class which contains an API call to send data to local servers, class 2 is a class that is called from a flow that grabs account and donation ids needed to pull more information that is done in class 1 and Class 3 is a test class that calls class 2 (I am assuming this test class is needed for validation).

When the inbound change set is running the validation on the classes, I am getting an error saying "*Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts*".

It is a single line of code that is causing this error and I have no idea how to get around it. I thought of commenting the line, push the code through and then uncomment in production, only to find out that classes are not able to be edited in production.

Not to sure how I am able to push a class that contains an API call to production while also including the test class. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you may want to take a look at this thread. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/testing-httpcallout-with-httpcalloutmock-and-unittest-created-data

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to create a mock callout class for your unit test.

Comment: So does that mean I would be pushing two test classes with the three other apex classes? Or would that first test class not be necessary with the mock callout class?